# async for loop not putting sqs message in queue

Tags: node.js, for-loop, aws-lambda

I am trying to inside a Lambda function run a for loop which will parse and send SQS messages to a certai queue. Currently it is running the for loop and creating the params properly (I checked via logging) and is running a log message just outside/after the for loop saying the lambda is done.

Issue is that the SQS message isn't being sent and/or arriving in the SQS queue.

I haven't inclued the rest of the lambda function as it is just noise and doesn't relate to the issue since it is running correctly already, the only issue is with the sqs message.

```
for (var i = 0; i < dogs.length; i++) {
      let MessageBody = JSON.stringify(dogs[i]);

            let params = {
                MessageBody,
                QueueUrl: process.env.serviceQueue,
                DelaySeconds: 0
            };
            sqs.sendMessage(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    logger.error(`sqs.sendMessage: Error message: ${err}`);
                } else {
                    let stringData = JSON.stringify(data);
                    logger.info(`sqs.sendMessage: Data: ${stringData}`);
                }
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iterating over multiple async requests, and using callback is a recipe for disaster as well as messy code. Id recommend the below (using async/await)

```
await Promise.all(dogs.map(async (dog) => {
  let params = {
    MessageBody: JSON.stringify(dog),
    QueueUrl: process.env.serviceQueue,
    DelaySeconds: 0
  }
  let data = await sqs.sendMessage(params).promise().catch(err => {
    logger.error(`sqs.sendMessage: Error message: ${err}`);
  });
  logger.info(`sqs.sendMessage: Data: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
}));
```

Comment: Thanks for the code example, it worked with a minor change, on line 3 there is a `=` which should be a `:` I figured I needed to use await in some way though ws unsure.

Comment: thanks for the update! ill modify the above for other folks